# Compute limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{|x|^{e^{1/|x|}}y}{x-y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone help me compute the following limit (if it exists)?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{|x|^{e^{1/|x|}}y}{x-y}$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch.  Let n be an appropriate positive integer:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{|x|^{exp(1/|x|)}y}{x-y}$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{|x|^{exp(1/|x|)}}{|x|^n} \frac{|x|^n y}{x-y}$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} |x|^{exp(1/|x|)-n} \frac{|x|^n y}{x-y}$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} |x|^{exp(1/|x|)-n} \displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|^n y}{x-y}$$
$$=0 \cdot 0$$
$$=0$$